# cannot toggle 'off' for dynamic window size/position in rainmeter skin

Tags: skin, rainmeter

I have a skin that shows the top 10 processes using my pc's RAM. I want to stop the skin from automatically resizing.

When the skin is initialized, if the content exceeds the specified size parameters, the skin is resized/moved to fit this content.

I have implemented a refresh button that I can use to get the skin back to its intended position, but this is a stop gap measure and I'd like it to *never change* regardless of the length of the content.

the `dynamicWindowSize` parameter seems like it should be doing this but it is having no effect when set to 0.

Curiously, this never happens with my CPU skin, which has identical parameter settings.

[image: rainmeter adapted illustro skin]

here is my skin:

```
[Rainmeter]
Author=Pul53dr1v3r
AppVersion=1.1
Background=#@#Background.png
BackgroundMode=3
BackgroundMargins=0,34,0,14
DynamicWindowSize=1

[Variables]
fontName=Consolas
textSize=8
colorBar=235,170,0,255
colorText=255,255,255,200

[MemTitleText]
Meter=STRING
MeterStyle=Style
StringAlign=CENTER
StringCase=UPPER
StringStyle=NONE
StringEffect=NONE
FontEffectColor=0,0,0,50
FontColor=#colorText#
FontFace=#fontName#
FontSize=11
AntiAlias=1
ClipString=1
X=100
Y=12
W=45
H=18
Text="R A M"

[Refresh]
Meter=IMAGE
ImageName=#@#white.png
X=180
Y=12
W=16
H=15
LeftMouseDownAction=!RainmeterRefreshApp

[MeasureTopMem]
Measure=Plugin
Plugin=Plugins\TopProcesses.dll
ReQuery=1
IgnoredProcesses=Idle|_Total|rundll32|wscript|userinit
MetricType=Memory
ProcNums=1-10
Format="%Memory - %pName"

[TopMemText]
Meter=String
MeterStyle=Style
MeasureName=MeasureTopMem
StringAlign=LEFT
StringCase=UPPER
StringStyle=BOLD
StringEffect=NONE
FontEffectColor=0,0,0,50
FontColor=250,250,250,200
FontFace=#fontName#
FontSize=#textSize#
AntiAlias=1
ClipString=1
X=35
Y=10R
```